# Export html to Excel with ASP

Tags: html, excel, asp-classic

I am trying to export an html table dynamically created in asp however, when I export to excel, all the td's are in a single cell in Excel. Any ideas how to make each td a different cell in Excel?

Here is my code:

```
<%  Set x = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    st = "&getdata=yes"
    x.Open "POST","https://www.mysite.com/exportToExcel.asp?",false 
    x.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    x.send st
    %>
    <table>
    <thead><tr>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Street Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Zip</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment;filename=filename.xls"
    Response.Write(x.responseText)%>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have never done this before so excuse my sloppy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try look here:

[Export Data to Excel using ASP](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/article.php?article=730)

or here:

[Building an Excel Spreadsheet using ASP](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Response.Clear

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Response.addHeader "content-disposition","attachment;filename=yourname.xls"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and no luck. I tried using the above method with a static html table and it works, just not one built dynamically.